# AlertDialog styling

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

We have a project that will run on different screen sizes the AlertDialog v7 AppComp has a style.

- My question is how to style the AlertDialog message text size?
- Second question how to change the size of the AlertDialog for various screen sizes?

I have written a CustomDialog as an Activity with it's own xml file and that seems to work fine except the emulator shows a ghost like view of the xml file when run! I have seen one post recent that implies that the text size of the message can not be changed. I have some knowledge of how to use DisplayMetrics but would rather not use this convention.

Design code for the AletDialog and style below. If someone can assure me the ghost image will not show up on a real device I might just give up and use this method, which seems clunky

```
    private void doWhat() {
    // R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle see res/values/styles
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Reset of Password");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Click YES to create a new master password");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.caution);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke YES event
            db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

            String q = "SELECT * FROM masterPW";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);
            // Above query gets TABLE_PW data from Col_IDI
            // TABLE_PW will only ever have one row of data

            int rowID = 99;
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                rowID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_IDI));
                str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_MPW));
            }
            cursor.close();

            // Line of code below WORKS deletes entire TABLE <=====
            // Not a recomended way to re-set the master password
            // db.delete(TABLE_PW, null, null);

            String num = Integer.toString(rowID);

            db.delete(TABLE_PW, Col_IDI + " = ?", new String[] { num });
            db.close();

            Intent intentYY = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this, MainActivity.class );
            startActivity( intentYY );
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password NOT Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    // Showing Alert Message and set the SIZE of the alertDialog
    alertDialog.show().getWindow().setLayout(1300, 500);// was 1100 500

}
    <!--Code below styles the AlertDialog.Builder on DetailsActivity -->
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_deepBlue</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/color_Black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_lightGray</item>
</style>
```

Comment: create custom layout for your alert dialog, this will give you all access to textview's styling, clicks and etc, then set your dialogs view to that layout..

Comment: @AalapPatel So just create a custom xml file only WITHOUT the ActivityCustom and inflate the custom xml inside the Activity that uses the CustomDialog

Comment: what is WITHOUT the ActivityCustom??

Comment: @AalapPatel I went about creating both and Activity and corresponding xml file so that was the first mistake. As per Grendel's answer I only need the xml file and a way to capture the view As a Nob I can make all manner of mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@James_Duh I deleted my prior answer after some extensive testing. Inflating the activity_custom.xml file has many problems. So the better idea is to use setContentView. You will still need to create activity_custom.xml for all device screens you will develop for code is below

Declare this like any other variable

```
 private Context context = this;
```

Then here is the method to open and display the activity_custom.xml file and show  your new and improved Dialog I tested on various devices and it works great

```
    public void doWhat(){

    final Dialog openDialog = new Dialog(context);
    openDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);
    Button btnYES = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnYES);
    // if YES delete Master Password from TABLE_MPW

    btnYES.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent( DetailsActivity.this, ListActivity.class );
            startActivity( intent );

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password WAS Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    openDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Little confused by this line of code  why the openDialog prefix I use Button btnYES = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnYES); and it failed Perhaps someone can elaborate on this but YES works great and simple as simple is nice

Answer (score 0):

For your kind of customization you need your own layout for alertdialog(not the default one) and to change the size of alert dialog you can use :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(); 
lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = 150;
lp.height = 500;
lp.x=-170;
lp.y=100;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

and to change the alert dialog theme, define your theme in your style.xml as:

```
<resources>
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and set the theme to dialog as:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new 
ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme));
```

hope this is all you need.

Comment: @Krantz So I create a custom.xml file and inflate it in the Activity that uses the dialog then in that Activity I use the LayoutParams to set the size for different devices  Still a little about "your own layout"

Comment: I have used the  <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item> in my style file and it does not change the text size of the dialog message text so I guess I need to know how to call a custom xml file in an Activity